# Distributed Locks for Redis Template

Tags: redis, locking, distributed

I am trying to figure how distributed locks are used/implemented in Redis using Redis Template. I have race condition scenario so cant use Optimistic Locking with Multi and Exec.

I see RedisLockService implmentations which implements org.springframework.cloud.cluster.lock.LockService but that has been deprecated. Is there something new that has replaced it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Redisson to implement a redis lock. there is a complete set of different distributed lock implementation in Redisson.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at RedisLockRegistry class provided by the Spring Integration Redis util package (org.springframework.integration.redis.util) which provides utlities for distributed locking in Redis. More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/redis/util/RedisLockRegistry.html).